# Running .sh Script With Sudo Results In Different Output

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo, subversion

I'm seeing some really strange behavior in a script I'm working on.What I have is an svn hook that gets run whenever a commit is made to an svn repo. It runs a sqsh command that generates another script (checkout.sh) and then executes that generated script. If I just run the script manually I get a result like this for the generated script:

```
/usr/bin/install -d /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/targetDir1; /usr/bin/svn checkout http://mysite.com/svn/sourceRepo/targetDir1 /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/targetDir1;
/usr/bin/install -d /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/targetDir2; /usr/bin/svn checkout http://mysite.com/svn/srcRepo/targetDir2 /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/targetDir2;
```

Notice How each line ends with a semi-colon.

If I run the same script but preface it with `/usr/bin/sudo -u myname`

then the generated script replaces the semicolon at the end of each line with a pipe '|' character. As a result, when the main script tries to actually execute that generated script it fails with an 'invalid end of file' error.

**Update**
Here are the scripts I'm trying to run:

**sudo-hook.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/sqsh -o ./checkout.sh -w 999999 -h -S myserver -D mydb -U dbuser -P apassword -C "select distinct '/usr/bin/install -d /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/'+cast(p.id as varchar(32) )+'; /usr/bin/svn checkout http://mysite.com/svn/srcRepo/'+cast(p.id as varchar(32) )+' /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/'+cast(p.id as varchar(32) ) from frame_skus as sku join products as p on p.id=sku.frame_id join frame_colors as c on c.id=sku.color_id join frame_sizes as s on s.id=sku.size_id join value_options as cc on c.color_code_id=cc.id join product_files as img on img.product_id=p.id  and img.color_id=c.id and img.dtype='FRAME_IMAGE' join brands as b on p.brand_id=b.id and b.id=69;"
./checkout.sh
```

**checkout.sh** (the generated script):

```
/usr/bin/install -d /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/31903; /usr/bin/svn checkout http://mysite.com/svn/31903 /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/31903|
/usr/bin/install -d /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/31904; /usr/bin/svn checkout http://mysite.com/svn/31904 /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/31904|
/usr/bin/install -d /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/31905; /usr/bin/svn checkout http://mysite.com/svn/31905 /opt/www/targetRepo/svn/31905|
```

Can someone please give me an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: Sudo resets much of the environment. Does your script rely on an Env var to generate the output?

Comment: You need to show us the script (and any other script that it depends on). Otherwise we can only make wild guesses.

Comment: Ok, I added some examples for the scripts I'm trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found the problem. Apparently it was sqsh that was adding those '|' characters. sqsh has a style (-m) flag and it seems if you don't set it explicitly then it defaults to the 'bcp' style which adds those extra characters.

What I would still like to know is why it defaults to one style 'bcp' when run with sudo but defaults to another style 'horizontal' when run without sudo.

Comment: Have you an SQSH environment variable set in one place but not the other? Or a `~/.sqshrc` file?

Comment: How would I check to see if that is the case?

Comment: the same way you'd check any other variable or file. `echo $SQSH` and `cat ~/.sqshrc`. Do this as yourself and then do `sudo -i` and repeat the two commands